# React. How to display only 3 elements from an array instead of 5 and how to make it so that when the timer expires, these elements randomly changed?

Tags: reactjs, timer

How to display only 3 elements from the array instead of 5 and how to make these elements randomly change after the timer expires? I understand that I need to create a function that pulls 3 random entries from the list, but how to implement this in practice? I used [use-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-local-storage) implementation. Thank you for answers!

This is my code:

```
    const CurrentEventsItem = () => {
    
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useLocalStorage('timer',  5 * 60)

    const getPadTime = (time) => time.toString().padStart(2, '0')

    const minutes = getPadTime(Math.floor(timeLeft / 60))
    const seconds = getPadTime(timeLeft - minutes * 60)

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimeLeft((timeLeft) => (timeLeft >= 1 ? timeLeft - 1 : setDisabled() ||  5 * 60))
        }, 1000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval) 
    }, [])

    const [appState, changeState] = useLocalStorage('CurrentEventsItem', {
        objects: [
            {id: v4(), title: 'Apple iPhone 13 Pro Max 256Gb (небесно-голубой)', avatar: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/147/147144.png', statusItem: false},
            {id: v4(), title: '500 Stars', avatar: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/147/147144.png', statusItem: false},
            {id: v4(), title: 'Sony PlayStation 5 Digital Edition', avatar: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/147/147144.png', statusItem: false},
            {id: v4(), title: 'XBOX 360 Digital Edition', avatar: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/147/147144.png', statusItem: false},
            {id: v4(), title: 'Google Nexus Digital Edition', avatar: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/147/147144.png', statusItem: false}
        ]
    })


    const toggleActive = (index) => {
        let arrayCopy = [...appState.objects];
        arrayCopy[index].statusItem = !arrayCopy[index].statusItem;
        changeState({...appState, objects: arrayCopy});
    }

    const toggleActiveStyles = (index) => {
        if (appState.objects[index].statusItem) {
          return 'current__events__hot-price disabled'
        } else {
          return 'current__events__hot-price'
        }
    }
    
    const toggleActiveStylesBtns = (index) => {
        if (appState.objects[index].statusItem) {
            return 'current__events__btn-green disabled'
        } else {
            return 'current__events__btn-green'
        }
    }

    const setDisabled = () => {
        appState.objects.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.statusItem) {
                toggleActive(index);
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className='current__events__wrapper'>
            {appState.objects.map((item, index) => 
                <div className="current__events__hot-price__item" key={index}>
                    <div className={toggleActiveStyles(index)}>
                        <h5 className="current__events__card-title__large">Hot Price</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div className="current__events__image">
                        <img src={item.avatar} alt='user' className="rounded-circle" width='75' height='75'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="current__events__info">
                        <h4 className="current__events__title__middle">{item.title}</h4>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className="current__events__timer">
                        <span>{minutes}</span>
                        <span>:</span>
                        <span>{seconds}</span>
                    </div>

                    <button className={toggleActiveStylesBtns(index)} onClick={() => toggleActive(index)} disabled={item.statusItem}>СДЕЛАТЬ ХОД</button> 
                </div> 
            )}

            
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default CurrentEventsItem
```

Comment: How is `useLocalStorage` implemented?

Comment: @decpk I used this one [use-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-local-storage)

Comment: where is `toggleActiveStyles`? You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you.

Comment: @decpk oh, i'm sorry! I added the missing `toggleActiveStyles` and `toggleActiveStylesBtns` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a state `selectedItems` which will contain random 3 elements.

```
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState(() =>
    getRandomElements(appState.objects, 3)
);
```

[`CODESANDBOX DEMO`](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-glitter-3keig2?file=/src/CurrentEventsItem.js)

then using `useEffect` hook you can change state if the timer reaches `0`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      const elements = getRandomElements(appState.objects, 3);
      setSelectedItems(elements);
    }
  }, [timeLeft, appState.objects]);
```

I'm passing state from the parent component and toggling the state based on id instead of index as:

```
  const toggleActive = (item) => {
    let arrayCopy = [...appState.objects];
    const toggledElement = arrayCopy.find((o) => o.id === item.id);
    if (toggledElement) {
      toggledElement.statusItem = !toggledElement.statusItem;
      changeState({ ...appState, objects: arrayCopy });
    }
  };
```